# Unicode mapping Error while opening INI files on MacOS

Tags: macos, delphi, unicode, firemonkey-fm3

I'm trying to open an INI file on Mac OSX using `TIniFile`:

```
SettingsFile := TIniFile.Create(aINIFileName);   //Ini vertion
Try
  iUpdateMaj := SettingsFile.ReadInteger('CurrentVersion', 'Maj', 0);
  iUpdateMin := SettingsFile.ReadInteger('CurrentVersion', 'Min', 0);
  iUpdateRel := SettingsFile.ReadInteger('CurrentVersion', 'Rel', 0);
Finally
  SettingsFile.Free;
End;
```

The exact error I got is:

> (EEncodingError) No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

This was working fine before in Yosemite, but since El Capitan it is no longer working.

From research I've done, the problem is related to Unicode endoding. I know that the INI file created with Notepad is encoded in UTF-8, and `TIniFile` use `TStrings` internally.

Does anyone have an idea how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Which line *specifically* is failing?  Is the problem related to opening an INI file that has a Unicode filename, or reading values from the INI using UTF-8 data?  It makes a big difference?  What does the call stack look like when the error is thrown?  What effort have you done so far to debug this yourself?

Comment: It fail at the .create line, more in depth, it break at:List.Text := FEncoding.GetString(Buffer, Size, Length(Buffer) - Size); line in the TMemIniFile.LoadValues proc in System.IniFiles, In the TEncoding.GetString I can see that the Error is raised because the ByteCount <0 and len =0 but I've no idea why this situation occur. The name of the ini file is RELEASE,INI and it is donwloaded from a HTML Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks perfectly fine if your .ini file is UTF-8 encoded and contains valid UTF-8 data. I don't know what is inside of your file, but it looks like your .ini file does not contain valid UTF-8 data.

So you'd have to find what encoding your .ini file uses. If your .ini file is ANSI, then you can open it like this:

```
SettingsFile := TIniFile.Create(aINIFileName, TEncoding.ANSI);
```

Comment: I appear that the file is ANSI. By adding TEncoding.ANSI, it's working. Sub question: using editor like Notepad can we force UTF-8 encoding ? I was certain that Notepad was encoding in UTF-8.

Comment: @AlainV yes, you can force UTF-8 in Notepad. In the "Save as" dialog, there is an Encoding option.

Answer (score 0):

This Works very Well for me:

Your code looks perfectly fine if your .ini file is UTF-8 encoded and contains valid UTF-8 data. I don't know what is inside of your file, but it looks like your .ini file does not contain valid UTF-8 data.

So you'd have to find what encoding your .ini file uses. If your .ini file is ANSI, then you can open it like this:

SettingsFile := TIniFile.Create(aINIFileName, TEncoding.ANSI);

Comment: are you on El Capitan like the original poster?

Comment: Actually i was trying with an Android Device; that is works fine..; but when i tryed on an iPad is not loading the info from the ini file :(

Comment: I Just tryed on a OSX El Capitan and Works fine!